# Is there a bug with parsing member access expressions on a user-defined integer literal in Clang and GCC?

Tags: c++, c++14, grammar, compiler-bug, user-defined-literals

The following code appears to be valid C++, accepted by all major compilers:

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

auto main()
    -> int
{
    using namespace std::string_literals;
    std::cout << "Hello"s.length();
}
```

The following, however, is rejected by both trunk versions of [Clang](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/tH9odPMPtu6BEi0k) and [GCC](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/mQvtjY3wYrzki0qu) (while being accepted by VC14):

```
#include <chrono>
#include <iostream>

auto main()
    -> int
{
    using namespace std::chrono_literals;
    std::cout << 42s.count(); // COMPILER ERROR HERE WITH CLANG AND GCC
}
```

Changing the problematic line to `(42s).count()` or `42s .count()` fixes the problem. A similar situation occurs with complex UDLs (again, rejected by [Clang](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/NSI0gMsRiRdpF3Fe) and [GCC](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/g2Z8fsinACljhUm1), accepted by VC):

```
#include <complex>
#include <iostream>

auto main()
    -> int
{
    using namespace std::complex_literals;
    std::cout << 42i.imag(); // COMPILER ERROR HERE WITH CLANG AND GCC
}
```

Is there a bug with parsing integer literals in Clang and GCC?

Comment: *pp-number*s are fun beasts.

Comment: @T.C. Thank you. I tried googling and didn't find that one.